# How is it correct to write this nested jQuery command?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, gridsplitter

I need something like:

```
function Splitter() {
    if ($(window).width() < 350) OR ($('#right-area').width() < 600) {
        $('.grid-item').css("width", "100%")
    }
    if ($(window).width() < 800) OR ($('#right-area').width() < 800) {
        $('.grid-item').css("width", "50%")
    }
    else {
        $('.grid-item').css("width", "33.3333%")
    }
}
```

How is it correct to write that? If I replace the `OR` with `||`, it does not work too.

Comment: Without knowing what your goal is, it's hard to say for certain what "correct" means. However, I'd imagine the second `if` should be an `else if`. Without it, your first `if` will always be overriden by the second, because there is no condition where the first is true but the second is not. (and `||` instead of `OR`)

Comment: Hmm. It does not work. :/

Comment: You're parentheses are also incorrect. You either need to encapsulate the entire set of conditions in a set of parentheses, *or* unwrap the individual conditions, like so:`if ($(window).width() < 350) || $('#right-area').width() < 600)`, for both `if ( ... )` blocks.

Comment: Which Parentheses do you mean?

Comment: An `if` must have *all of its conditions* wrapped in a single set of parentheses. However, your `if` statements look like this: `if (a) || (b)`, which is invalid. It needs to be `if ( (a) || (b) )` *or* `if (a || b)`

Answer (score 1):

You should try it:

```
function Splitter() {
    if (($(window).width() < 350) || ($('#right-area').width() < 600)) {
        $('.grid-item').css("width", "100%")
    }
    if (($(window).width() < 800) || ($('#right-area').width() < 800)) {
        $('.grid-item').css("width", "50%")
    } else {
        $('.grid-item').css("width", "33.3333%")
    }
}
```

I thought you forgot "(" or ")" in statement

Comment: The task would be to minify this commands:
`function Splitter() {
    if ($('#rechts').width() < 600) {
        $('.grid-item').css("width", "100%")
    } else if ($('#rechts').width() < 800) {
        $('.grid-item').css("width", "50%")
    } else {
        $('.grid-item').css("width", "33.3333%")
    }
    if ($(window).width() < 800) {
        $('.grid-item').css("width", "50%")
    }
    if ($(window).width() < 350) {
        $('.grid-item').css("width", "100%")
    }
}`

The problem here is that the commands contradict in some cases.

Comment: Logically this still doesn't make sense. There is no possible value for `$(window).width()` or `$('#right-area').width()` where the first condition isn't overwritten by the second.

Comment: And how would you write it then?

Answer (score 0):

When using an `if`, all corresponding conditions must be wrapped in a single set of parentheses.

Consider the following:

```
if (a) || (b)   // invalid
if (a || b)     // valid
if ((a) || (b)) // valid
```

Additionally, I believe your logic is a bit off.

Let's say `$(window).width()` is `200`.

Your first  condition is true, so `$(".grid-item")` gets set to `width: 100%`.

The second `if` is **also** true, so `$(".grid-item")` gets set to `width: 50%`.

There is no scenario where `$('.grid-item').css("width", "100%")` fires and isn't immediately overwritten by `$('.grid-item').css("width", "50%")`.

---

I believe this may be more along the lines of what you're looking for:

```
function Splitter() {
    if ($(window).width() < 350 || $('#right-area').width() < 600) {
        $('.grid-item').css("width", "100%")
    }
    else if ($(window).width() < 800 || $('#right-area').width() < 800) {
        $('.grid-item').css("width", "50%")
    }
    else {
        $('.grid-item').css("width", "33.3333%")
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh nice! That really helps. But there is still one problem: If the window size is under 600px, the widths of the grid items are by 100%, but they should be by 50% as long the window size is not under 350px. Is it possible to add there a »!important«?

Comment: The code does as you suggest. It will be set to `50%` if the window width is between `350` and `800` *(ignoring the `$('#right-area').width()` portion)*.

Comment: My page is splitted in two parts with a resizable jQuery splitter. At the right side is a Masonry image grid gallery. If the window size is under 800px, the »right part« arranges vertical under the »left part«. With your code everything works fine. If I resize the splitter position, the images arrange correctly. But: If I resize the window size under 800px, the images are 100% wide, but they should be in this case by 50%.

Comment: In the scenario where the window size is under `800px` but the images are staying `100%` width, what is the width of `$('#right-area')`? Your condition will keep `width: 100%` if it's `< 600`.

Comment: If the window size is under 800px, #right-area will be in the same width as the window size. Do you have an idea how to fix that? The $(window).width() commands should be more important than the $('#right-area').width() commands.

Comment: There is no logical association for "more important". You need to define black-and-white conditions for when the widths should be applied. Perhaps `$('#right-area').width()` doesn't matter at all...?

Comment: The #right-area width is important if the splitter position changes. But if the window gets resized, the $(window).width() commands should overwrite the $('#right-area').width() commands.

Comment: If the logic is different for window resize vs splitter drag, then you'll need to handle those two events separately. Unfortunately without the ability to recreate any of this or see the behavior, I can't really help much more.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you, to use another approach. You can try to use [jQuery#css](https://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function) with function callback:

```js
var banner = $("#banner-message")
banner.css('width', () => {
 const windowWidth = $(window).width();
 const rightAreaWidth = $('#right-area').width();
 return windowWidth < 350 || rightAreaWidth < 600 ? '100%' : windowWidth < 800 || rightAreaWidth < 800 ? '50%' : '33%';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
</div>
```